# GPIO Pin connection with Game hat

Tags: gpio, retropie

I got a [Raspberry Pi 1 B+, 2014 v1.2 board](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-1-model-b-plus/), and I was trying to attach it to [Waveshare's Game hat](https://www.waveshare.com/game-hat.htm)

The main issue which I have is, the raspberry board has 4 dead GPIO pins (tested using [pigpio](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=180505)), 10,11,25 and 26. Pin 10, 11 and 25 are not in use by Game hat, as per the Game hat manual, [here](http://C:%5CUsers%5CTejashwi%20Kalp%20Taru%5CDownloads%5CDocuments%5CGame_HAT_user_manual_en.pdf)

Everything is working fine with the hat, but some keys are not working which may be due to the dead GPIO pin no.25 which is ground pin and it is used by Game hat.

Now the question is, that the dead GPIO pin 25 is a ground pin, and it is used by the Game hat, can I connect the pin 25 with any other ground pin (using a wire), for example, 6, 9, 14? Will it work?
I think that every ground pin is basically the same, connected to a single ground, so sharing or connecting to each other might not be an issue?

Comment: How can a ground pin be "dead"? Is it somehow disconnected?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking the same and confused, PIGPIO shows dead pin 10,11,25 and 26. Seems like they are not actual PIN number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I was actually confused with PIGPIO results 10,11,25 and 26. Turned out that the pin numbers which PIGPIO displayed are not the actual PIN number, [here's the mapping of PINS](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/#Type_3)

Now upon mapping, I found out that:

1. PIGPIO PIN 10 -> PIN NO 19 on board -> Not used by game hat
2. PIGPIO PIN 11 -> PIN NO 23 on board -> Not used by game hat
3. PIGPIO PIN 25 -> PIN NO 22 on board -> Not used by game hat
4. PIGPIO PIN 26 -> PIN NO 37 on board -> A button of controller

And that's why the button is not working